# AWS Lambda error on Cognito User Pool trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to insert a record into DynamoDB invoking "Pre sign-up" trigger of Cognito User Pool.

Lambda function is pretty simple for testing purposes but there is always an error in client application on AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool.signUp call

**Use case 1**

Lambda body:

```
console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
```

Result:

```
InvalidLambdaResponseException: Invalid lambda function output : Invalid JSON
```

**Use case 2**

Lambda body:

```
callback("null", "success");
```

Result:

```
InvalidLambdaResponseException: Invalid lambda function output : Invalid JSON
```

**Use case 3**

Lambda body:

```
new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient().put(params, callback);
```

Result:

```
InvalidLambdaResponseException: Invalid cognito sign in version. Version should be 1
```

So, any ideas what might be wrong?

Could the latest error might be related to the beta status of Cognito User Pool?

P.S. I will provide more details if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need return the same `event` in the callback, as well said  @user1268855 `callback(null, event);` in my case I don't return `null` as string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are doing this in node.js and the error indicates you are not returning the service expected event source.

You should call context.done() when your lambda function finishes execution. Also, in any of the trigger sources which Cognito User Pool service generates, you can only edit the "response" part of the the source. For example, "autoConfirmUser" flag in PreSignUp trigger source.

Look at the examples in our [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html) for more details on this.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I remember I read somewhere that I need to deal with `context` but after thousand pages of different documentations it's already kinda a mess in the head :) Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Stanislau - I'm facing the exact problem while trying to insert user data to dynamodb on the post confirmation trigger in user pool. Can you please let me know how you resolve this?

Comment: @Asa - So, as Chetan mentioned in his response, `context.done()` makes the job. In your lambda function you just need to invoke at some point either `context.done(null, event)` or `context.done(err)` (e.g. `exports.handler = (event, context) => {"your code here"; context.done(null, event)}`

Comment: @Stanislau - Thanks a lot. I'll try this out and let you know of the progress. Since I've started working on some other project, it'll take couple of days for me to test this out.

Comment: Is `context.done` still the way to go? Or should one be using the 3rd argument to the handler `callback`? I remember reading somewhere that the use of `callback` was a replacement for `context.done` and others but I still see the `context` way used and discussed.

Comment: Does anybody know how to solve this issue in python lambda? There is no `contex.done()` method, and no `callback` as third param as in `nodejs` lambdas.

Comment: I just want to point out that calling the callback function with the event works as well. `callback(null, event);` or if you need to return an error `callback(err);`

Comment: @ivanBorshchov for this callback("null", "success");  in node is equivalent in python return event

Comment: fyi: context.done() is now deprecated

Comment: context.done() seems to be deprecated, callback(null, event) is the recommended way, Just in case if someone is using async methods, then you can return Promise.resolve(event) and Promise.reject(error) in a try catch block

Answer (score 9):

@user3479125 
To do the same in python just return an event as is, or with modifications in datasets.

This code is supposed to run between the mobile device and cognito, so it can modify the event and it should return it back, so Sync event will finish successfully.

Some more explanations [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/introducing-amazon-cognito-events-sync-triggers/)

Comment: Thanks, Mykhail. Huge help

Comment: Thanks a lot! Weird that no one ever bothered to mention this anywhere in the docs, apart from that one mention in the blog.

Comment: Thanks @Mykhail Martsyniuk!

Answer (score -6):

Try returning `callback("null", event);`

This should solve your problem.

Comment: `null` should not be in quotes (otherwise it is a string and not null), it should be `callback(null, event)`