# Is an AWS user pool sync trigger possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, triggers, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-nodejs

**Question**

I have a lambda function triggered when someone registers via federated identities that creates an entry in a dynamodb table.

I want the same function (or similar) to occur when a user registers (I was thinking post confirm) via an associated user pool.

**Background (what I've attempted)**

I've linked the federated identity to the user pool but the lambda linked to the Cognito trigger does not get called for user pools. I thought it may not support the same process (is this the case?) and tried adding a customised workflow trigger to the user pool for post confirm. I just get an error back (bad request 400) stating '{"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"User cannot confirm."}' although the user is showing as confirmed in Cognito.

I've looked at the documentation but I don't see many clear examples. The best I found was one emailing on post confirm which I modified to contain a basic dynamo call as follows:

```
var doc = require('dynamodb-doc');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log(event);

    if (event.request.userAttributes.email) {
            var db = new doc.DynamoDB();
            var tableName = 'Users'
            var user = {
                'id' : event.identityId,
                'name' : event.datasetRecords.name.newValue,
                'email' : event.datasetRecords.email.newValue,
            };

            var params = {
                'TableName' : tableName,
                'Item' : user
            };

            console.log('Inserting user', params);

            db.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
                console.log(err, data);

                if (err) {
                    console.log('User insert failure', err);
                    context.done(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('User insert success', data);
                    context.done(null, event);
                }
            });
    } else {
        // Nothing to do, the user's email ID is unknown
        context.done(null, event);
    }
};
```

I've looked at similar questions and nearest I found was this
[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423865/aws-lambda-error-on-cognito-user-pool-trigger)
although it does not include a working code snippet. I've tried a few variations but no luck!

As stated there I have also seen callbacks used in other examples so it would be good to clear up what the preferred and working code should look like!

I would also like to know if it should return data within the context.done in a particular format as I saw some [set responses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-post-confirmation) like the following:

```
"response": {
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Calling ConfirmSignUp on already confirmed user throws the error "User cannot confirm". As a result of that post confirmation lambda function is not called. Though this error could be more descriptive.

Have you looked at this example from the docs already?
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#aws-lambda-triggers-post-confirmation-example

Comment: The lambda function is being called on post confirm trigger and the user has not already been confirmed so I don't see why it would give an error that it was already confirmed?Yes, the code above is modified from the example in your link! I've replace the email send with a database entry. I've also just tried it with just logs and still get issues.

Comment: If I remove the trigger it confirms fine. Is there an issue with the code above and if so please code you post a working example?