# Cognito Post Confirmation Trigger adminAddUserToGroup: "Invalid lambda function output : Invalid JSON"

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I set the following lambda function as the post-confirmation trigger in Cognito. Anyone know why I'm receiving "Invalid lambda function output : Invalid JSON"?

I'm getting log from "console.log("params", params)" in CloudWatch but not from "console.log("inside adminAddUserToGroup", params)".

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

type TriggerEvent = {
  version: string,
  region: string,
  userPoolId: string,
  userName: string,
  callerContext: {
    awsSdkVersion: string,
    clientId: string
  },
  triggerSource: string,
  request: {
    userAttributes: {
        sub: string,
        'cognito:email_alias': string,
        'cognito:user_status': string,
        birthdate: string,
        email_verified: string,
        gender: string,
        preferred_username: string,
        email: string
    }
  },
  response: {}
}

exports.handler = async (event:TriggerEvent, context: any, callback: any) => {
    var cognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-18' });

    console.log("event", event);
    var params = {
        GroupName: 'customers',
        UserPoolId: event.userPoolId,  
        Username: event.userName
    };
    console.log("params", params)
    try {
        cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminAddUserToGroup(params, function(err: any, data: any) {
            console.log("inside adminAddUserToGroup", params)
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.Stack);
                context.done(err);
            }
            context.done();
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Add user to group catch err", err);
        context.fail("Add user to group catch err");
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: Not yet, sorry, I moved on..

Answer (score 0):

There are two different problems in the code:

**Fixing the missing output of `console.log("inside adminAddUserToGroup", params)`:**

You should `await` on the `adminAddUserToGroup(..).promise()`, otherwise the lambda will proceed and complete before the adminAddUserToGroup fully executes. You can check this by adding a `console.log("Lambda completed")` after the try/catch block and see that it does show.

Fix it with:

```
await cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminAddUserToGroup(params, function(err: any, data: any) {
    console.log("inside adminAddUserToGroup", params)
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.Stack);
        context.done(err);
    }
    context.done();
}).promise();
```

**Fixing the "Invalid lambda function output : Invalid JSON" response:**

You need to return the event, usage of [`context.done()` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54854789) and, since you are using an `async` handler, you should use `return` or `throw`, for success and failure respectively, as per the AWS documentation on [Async handler for Typescript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/typescript-handler.html#async-typescript).

Fix it by replacing `context.done();` with `return event;`.